# Intellij, generate public static final class EDIT_CLASS_NAME { } automcatically for innerclasses

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there a hotkey or something similar to psvm ( tab ) to generate a custom class.

I am tired of having to type int **public static final class ... {}** for every innerclass I need. It's nice to use for testing as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do that by creating the following live template in settings -> editor -> livetemplates:

```
public static final class $VAR$ {
        $END$
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any but it really isn't much typing.

`psf`<kbd>tab</kbd> gives 'public static final ', c<kbd>tab</kbd> gives `class`, enter your name and <kbd>{</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> and you're done.